# Enabling Intel Virtualization VT in DG31PR

Tags: windows-7, ubuntu, virtualbox, virtualization, bios

Related to [this](https://superuser.com/questions/22915/how-do-i-enable-vt-x) question

Motherboard : DG31PR

Processor: E6300 , 2.66 GHz, 64 bit, Supports VT-X as per Intel.

BIOS Version : Unknown

I'm unable to find Virtualization option in BIOS to enable it. I want to run a Windows 7 64 bit image in VirtualBox from Ubuntu 9.04. Windows 7 installation says something like "CPU is not 64 bit". How to enable the VT-X option in my BIOS?  I have searched across multiple forums and sites and yet to find a solution. I can upgrade my BIOS if some version which supports VT is available. If no offical solutions are available, hacks are welcome unless it don't brick my MB.

Note: At work now, so didn't execute the Securable tool, but as per the details in Intel website, E6300 supports VT-X.

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you first need to update the motherboard to the latest [BIOS Version](http://downloadmirror.intel.com/17851/eng/BIOS%20Update%20Readme.pdf) available [here](http://downloadcenter.intel.com/Filter_Results.aspx?strTypes=all&ProductID=2839&OSFullname=OS+Independent&strOSs=38).

This should enable the VT option in the BIOS. Once done you can enable it as long as the Processor support VT. This can be confirmed [here]((http://www.tomshardware.com/news/windows-xp-mode-virtualization-intel,7709.html). There is also an official list on the Intel website but I can't find it right now.

Answer (score 1):

When in doubt you can always try the small utility [SecurAble](http://www.grc.com/securable.htm), it will tell you if you have VT enabled or not.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be a problem.

1. Microsoft forum: [**Can't Run XP Applications using Virtual XP Mode in Win 7 RC Build 7100**](http://social.answers.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/GettingReadyforWindows7/thread/efab41b5-f189-494b-9e9d-9ee7e6fef55f)

   - Intel forum: [**DG31PR with BIOS PRG3110H.86A.0065 No VMX**](http://communities.intel.com/message/16118)

Comment: @nik : Thanks for quick reply. But atleast those guys reported the issue has Virtualization option in BIOS. I don't even have that option visible in BIOS

Comment: @blntechie, have you compared the BIOS versions with those on these pages?

Comment: @nik Yet to do that. In work, need to check and update if needed.