# Enabling virtualization on a PC

Tags: virtualization, bios, ios, sdk

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I enable VT-X?](https://superuser.com/questions/22915/how-do-i-enable-vt-x)

I was designing games in unity with some friends but none of us have a Mac so none of us can download the Apple SDK.  To use the SDK, we will have to run a virtual machine with OSX on it.  Virtualization is disabled on most PCs by default and I was wondering if there was any way to change that without rebooting into the BIOS.  If not, how would I change it in the BIOS?

Answer (score 0):

Look for the "Virtualization" or "VT" option in your BIOS and enable it.  You'll normally have to do this before the Operating System boots.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need VT to virtualise unless you're running a 64 bit VM on a 32 bit system. I'd note tho that you can't 'just' install OS X in a VM on a windows/linux system since it detects that you're running on hardware that isn't made by apple.

Of course, there's ways to but hackintoshes are out of the scope of superuser.