# Can anyone confirm whether or not the ASUS N53SV-DH72 supports VT-x?

Tags: laptop, virtualization, vt-x

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I enable VT-X?](https://superuser.com/questions/22915/how-do-i-enable-vt-x)

It has the [Intel Core i7-2670QM 2.2GHz processor](http://ark.intel.com/products/53469/Intel-Core-i7-2670QM-Processor-%286M-Cache-2_20-GHz%29) which does support VT-x (), but I'm more interested in making sure that the bios supports it.  I've heard some laptop manufacturers disable it in bios (without the option to enable it) even though the hardware supports it, so I was hoping someone might have this laptop and can confirm first-hand whether or not it is available.

Comment: @techie007  appearantly she dosnt own the laptop and wants to check if this feature is intregrated or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have the N53SV too and there is an option in bios to enable/disable VT-x ().Just when you turn on your pc, press F2 and go to bios config and you will see the option to enable it.VT-x () is already enabled by default.This laptop is one of the bests and fastest laptops on the new and you may be sure about its supports VT-x.
You may buy a SATA3 SSD(eg patriot pyro) IF using vmware alot and speed really matters.