# Stuck on "Making the filesystem usable"

Tags: virtualbox, puppylinux

I have been using
[Puppy Linux](http://puppylinux.org)
with
[VirtualBox](http://virtualbox.org). I updated my Puppy to the new version and now it will not boot. It gives the message

```
Making the filesystem usable
```

and hangs at that point.

[Puppy Won't Boot in a VirtualBox](http://forums.virtualbox.org/viewtopic.php?t=55921)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> You need a 64-bit processor with hardware virtualization support

[§ 3.1.2. 64-bit guests](http://virtualbox.org/manual/ch03.html#intro-64bitguests)

Now while I do have this, it was not turned on in the BIOS.

[How do I enable VT-X?](https://superuser.com/q/22915/#179586)