# VT-x error when setting up VirtualBox on Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, virtualbox, vt-x

I have tried to setup VirtualBox on Ubuntu, but I get this error even though  Intel virtualization technology (VT-x) is set to `Yes` in the BIOS:

> Failed to open a session for the virtual machine Ubuntu.
>
> VT-x is disabled in the BIOS for both all CPU modes > (VERR_VMX_MSR_ALL_VMX_DISABLED).
>
> Result Code: E_FAIL (0x80004005)
> Component: ConsoleWrap
> Interface: IConsole {872da645-4a9b-1727-bee2-5585105b9eed}

EDIT: according to SecurAble my system is able to handle virtualization:

[image: Securable screenshot]

Comment: That setting is disabled in your BIOS. You will have to enable it.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I enable VT-X?](http://superuser.com/questions/22915/how-do-i-enable-vt-x)

Comment: @MC10 --- Virtualization Technology setting is enabled in my bios.  I already checked that.

Comment: Then see the first answer in the possible duplicate and make sure your hardware is supported.

Comment: @MC10 - Securable shows that my system is capable of virtualiztion.

Comment: Then have you enabled it in the VirtualBox settings itself? I can't think of where else it is going wrong. Maybe see the info [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20647610/verr-vmx-msr-vmxon-disabled-when-starting-an-image-from-oracle-virtual-box).

Comment: @MC10 that was the case --- You are trying to allocate >3GB of RAM to the VM.
Similar to the previous point, this requires: (a) a 64 bit host system; and (b) true hardware pass-through ie VT-x.

Comment: I see. Perhaps you could post an answer as to how you solved it in case anyone else comes across this.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

What solved my issue was using less than 3 GB of ram in the virtual box session.  I was originally attempting to utilize roughly 6 GB.

> You are trying to allocate >3GB of RAM to the VM.
>   This requires: (a) a 64 bit host system; and (b) true hardware pass-through ie VT-x.

Comment: This is so weird, it used to work for me and I hadn't changed anything (I had RAM set to 4GB). Thanks for posting this.

Comment: Have the exact same issue. Been using my VM on 8GB for months and today for no reason it's complaining about VT-x even though it is enabled. Must be a bug in VirtualBox. Dropping to 3GB takes it further but I can't run my 64bit Guest OS now since it thinks it's on a 32bit architecture and is incompatible. :(

Answer (score 5):

In my case Memory(RAM) was not a problem, just VT-x wasn't enabled in BIOS. Or in some cases, CPU may not have support of VT at all.

To check whether your CPU supports it or not. try:

```
sudo apt-get install cpu-checker
sudo kvm-ok
```

Second command will output if VT is enabled or not or if it's available at all.

If it does, go to BIOS and enable it. It should be named `Intel Virtualization Technology,` `Intel VT-x,` `Virtualization Extensions,` `Vanderpool,` or something similar.

Comment: I get `INFO: Your CPU does not support KVM extensions
KVM acceleration can NOT be used`. My proc is `Intel(R) Pentium(R) CPU B960 @ 2.20GHz`

Answer (score 1):

I've been dealing with this issue for a few hours, trying to solve it with probably all the answers I could find on the Internet.

What have worked for me was removing Hyper-V role from my Windows...

MJ

Comment: What was your VTX error you were getting?

Comment: Same for me. I was getting "VT-x is not available". Elaborated that [here](http://superuser.com/a/1138886/112204)