# Ubuntu error when running Virtualbox

Tags: windows, ubuntu, virtualbox

My computer runs Ubuntu Game Pack, and I downloaded Virtualbox on it to run Windows, but when I go through the setup and try to launch the actual virtual machine, I get this error:

> Failed to open a session for the virtual machine Windows 10.
>
> VT-x is disabled in the BIOS for all CPU modes (VERR_VMX_MSR_ALL_VMX_DISABLED).
>
> Result Code: NS_ERROR_FAILURE (0x80004005)
> Component: ConsoleWrap
> Interface: IConsole {872da645-4a9b-1727-bee2-5585105b9eed}

How can I resolve this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [VT-x error when setting up VirtualBox on Ubuntu](https://superuser.com/questions/957132/vt-x-error-when-setting-up-virtualbox-on-ubuntu).  This is an exact duplicate, so I am not interested in having a discussion, but I suspect VT-x is simply disabled and you have to enable it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Follow the methods described below to solve your issue-

**Method-1:**

To run Virtual Box on 64-bit host there is a need to enable Virtualization Technology (VTx) in the BIOS. In some PCs, Virtualization Technology Directed I/O (VTd) is to be enabled also. Usually these setting are disabled on the level of BIOS. To enable VTx and/or VTd you have to change corresponding settings in the BIOS.

Here is an example on how to do it (The steps are not exact for your particular PC. But you will find similar options in your PC BIOS settings):

- Start the machine
- Enter into BIOS (Some Key Combination which is dependent on your motherboard model)
- Go to Security -> System Security
- Enable Virtualization Technology (VTx) and/or Virtualization Technology Directed I/O (VTd)
- Save and restart the machine

If the above method fails i.e. VTx and/or VTd is already enabled in your BIOS, then follow the method described below:

**Method-2:**

Follow the steps below in your VirtualBox Manager:

- Select the Virtual device and choose Settings
- Navigate to System and click the Processor tab
- Tick the check-box, Enable PAE/NX

This should solve your issue.

Comment: I've attempted both methods you posted

Comment: I have virtualbox downloaded, and i can run it, but I cant aunch a virtual machine

Comment: which operating system is loaded on that virtual machine you can't run

Comment: i can't run windows 10

Comment: after following above methods, what is the state of error, does same message appear, is your operating system installed successfully on that particular virtual machine?

Comment: I can't launch the virtual machine because it gives me that error

Comment: that means, according to you `VERR_VMX_MSR_ALL_VMX_DISABLED` is still appearing as error when you tried to launch the machine, did you completely shut down and restart both host and guest pc after follwing the methods in the answer? If you haven't done so, try to do those. But the same error message shouldn't appear if you had done the steps described

Comment: It still doesn't work

Comment: And i cant do method one because I cant start the machine

Comment: actually method one is not for your virtual box...it is related to your physical pc bios settings

Comment: my coputer is single boot linux, how do I do this?

Comment: what is your laptop model/ pc motherboard model (if you don't know the exact model, please state the brand at least)...

Comment: leveno yoga . .

Comment: Follow this link http://www.thewindowsplanet.com/3192/how-to-enable-virtualization-on-a-lenovo-computer-on-windows.htm

Comment: If you can do those steps successfully, your problem should be solved by then. But if you are still facing the same problem after that, then more info should be provided to find out the actual cause...  please edit your question and provide...your laptop model/pc motherboard model/brand, your guest system configuration (OS, 32 bit/ 64 bit, RAM), your virtual machines configuration (The OS you have installed (32-bit / 64-bit), allocated RAM) etc.